# restrict access to the admin url by ip in django with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to restrict access to the admin section of my django app by using simple host-based access control in nginx. 
Unfortunately nginx does not seem to abide by the configuration request:

this is my setting for this particular section in nginx:

```
# gunicorn setup
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }


 location /admin/ { # restrict access to admin section
    allow 192.168.0.1;
    deny all;
 }
```

This does still block my ip 192.168.0.1.
What am I doing wrong?
Is there another way to block access to the /admin/ section of a django app?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem by replacing the /admin/ location with the following:

```
location ^~ /admin/ { # restrict access to admin section
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    allow 192.168.0.1;
    deny all;
}
```

I hope this will save someone some long searches on the internet.
I would appreciate answers offering a better solution.

Comment: Is there also a way to configure that on gunicorn level? I'm asking, because I'm deploying my application with Docker and don't want to have a dependency to my nginx-proxy container. I wanna clearly separate both from each other that's why I would like to configure that on gunicorn web server level.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using an AWS Load Balancer**
Then you will run into an issue where the IP being passed is not the client IP but rather the IP of the LB.

You will need a different blocking mechanism here.
**Do the following precisely.**

**Add the following to the top level `http` block:**

```
    # The X-Forwarded-For is the client IP which is what we need insted of the
# load balancer IP
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;

log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_local '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"' ;

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
```

**Add the following to the `server` block.** replace that `x.x.x.x` with your VPN or whitelisted IP. For example: `?44\.231\.29\.79?$`

```
# Only allow access to admin panel through VPN IP
location ^~ /admin/ { # restrict access to admin section
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    set $allow false;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_for ~ " ?x\.x\.x\.x?$") {
        set $allow true;
    }

    if ($http_x_forward_for ~ " ?x\.x\.x\.x$") {
        set $allow false;
    }

    if ($allow = false) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Answer taken from AWS forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=62474#