# how to prevent access to admin urls in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, webfaction

`Django` gives `admin url` automatically, such as `www.example.com/admin`.
I do not want any outside visitors to access this url. This should be accessed only with in the host and allowed `IP address`.
If I try to access to `https://instagram.com/admin/` (which is built using `Django`),it gives `404 page not Found error`
How can I achieve the same behavior?

what is the preferred and right way to do it?

I host my `webservice` in`webfaction` and allowing `IP address` of host means other webfaction account-holders might be able to access the admin URL which I dont want to. Looking for a neat and simple way

Thanks:

PS: I see a similar question posted here but that is with respect to [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831994/how-to-prevent-access-of-admin-pages-by-knowing-the-admin-page-url). I am wondering how can I acheive the same using `Django`?

Comment: You could build a decorator around the admin URLs -- either manually by reproducing the URLs or perhaps programmatically using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411661/1345536.  The decorator could then check for whitelisted IP addresses or return a 404.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One common method, which is advocated by Two Scoops of Django, is to change your admin url. Thus, rather than logging into your admin at `www.example.com/admin/`, you would log in at `www.example.com/supers3cret4dm1n/` or something  that you've set.  This is likely what Instagram has done in your example.

Example code:

```
urlpatterns = patterns(''
    ...
    url(r'^supers3cret4dm1n/', include(admin.site.urls)), # Change the pattern to whatever you want here
    ...
)
```

Note that this doesn't make it accessible from only one IP address, but it does effectively 'hide' your admin login page.

Another tip is to use the `django-admin-honeypot` package. This sets up a fake admin page at `www.example.com/admin` while having your real admin page at another site that you've set. Then, django-admin-honeypot will alert you if anyone tries to hack your admin at the fake admin site.

EDIT:

If you're dead-set on restricting by IP address, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208535/restrict-access-to-the-admin-url-by-ip-in-django-with-nginx-and-gunicorn) a SO question and answer showing how to do it with nginx. I imagine it'd be similar with others.

Comment: what you suggested seems reasonable rather than playing around with IP address

Comment: But that still doesnt stop bots from crawling the URL. And if you dissallow that in robots.txt, then anyone who looks at robots file can find the URL.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can treat the admin path as a secret, so set it as an environment variable in your system and then retrieve it (good approach if your source code is public).

```
ADMIN_URL_PATH = os.getenv('DJANGO_ADMIN_PATH')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path(ADMIN_URL_PATH, admin.site.urls)
    ...
]
```